# teleop_twist_joy with Logitech F710 Joystick force feedback error

Tags: ros, joystick

I am using a Logitech F710 joystick game controller in ROS Kinetic Kame. I was able to perform `jstest` testing, and can see my joystick works well.

But when I try to use joystick with Turtlesim or with simple teleop_twist_joy, I see this error :`[ERROR] [1567106281.990244467]: Couldn't open joystick force feedback!` and there is no response on the screen in turtlesim or in the terminal itself.

Here's entire terminal log:

```
$user@user: roslaunch teleop_twist_joy teleop.launch ... logging to /home/sma1/.ros/log/2bdd147a-ca8f-11e9-80dc-5891cf766ee3/roslaunch-user-14722.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://user:44089/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /joy_node/autorepeat_rate: 20
 * /joy_node/deadzone: 0.3
 * /joy_node/dev: /dev/input/js0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /teleop_twist_joy/axis_angular: 0
 * /teleop_twist_joy/axis_linear: 1
 * /teleop_twist_joy/enable_button: 8
 * /teleop_twist_joy/enable_turbo_button: 10
 * /teleop_twist_joy/scale_angular: 0.4
 * /teleop_twist_joy/scale_linear: 0.7
 * /teleop_twist_joy/scale_linear_turbo: 1.5

NODES
  /
    joy_node (joy/joy_node)
    teleop_twist_joy (teleop_twist_joy/teleop_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[joy_node-1]: started with pid [14739]
process[teleop_twist_joy-2]: started with pid [14740]
[ERROR] [1567106281.990244467]: Couldn't open joystick force feedback!
```

Comment: I commented on your other copy of this question [over at Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/19390/9720). What troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: Replied it there. Let's continue discussion there.